# Force scripts on Windows server to use Wi-Fi adapter

Tags: windows-10, networking, self-hosting

In a small company we have set up a PC running Windows 10 as a 'server' and it is connected to the internet via Ethernet and Wi-Fi as well, through different ISPs. 
The Ethernet connection is behind a hardware firewall that disables SMTP requests, which does not allow us to send automatic e-mails from a recently installed [offline Wekan](https://github.com/wekan/wekan/wiki/Offline) kanban system through [gmail SMTP](https://github.com/wekan/wekan/wiki/Troubleshooting-Mail#example-gmail). However, if we switch to Wi-Fi, it works seamlessly.
So, is there a way to force the Wekan application (essentially a .bat file that calls a main .js script and then others) to use the wireless connection of the 'server'? We do not want to operate the server only through Wi-Fi as it works as a file server as well, and in that aspect through Ethernet.
After a lot of googling, I found ForceBindIP, but that works only with .exe files, right? Anyway, I could not make it work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: applications don't decide what interface to use to reach a target location. Binding is about server processes, not about clients (and in your SMTP scenario, your application is a client, not a server).  Client applications use IP Routes to determine what network interface traffic will be sent out through. in this case, I'd recommend you create an IP Route that exits via the Wifi interface, for the google service IPs you are planning to send your SMTP traffic to. that way only the traffic you want to send to google will be treated differently.

Comment: @FrankThomas thanks a lot for your input. After googling about routing table I managed to make it work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @bandika please do not add "Solved" to a question's title. The site already reflects if an answer is available as long as you accept one, which you did.

Comment: sorry for the rookie mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment from [FrankThomas](https://superuser.com/users/171793/frank-thomas) I extended the Windows Routing table with Google's IPs attached to the Wi-Fi network's gateway. That got the e-mails going.

Command Prompt (with admin rights):

```
route add -p [gmail service ip] mask 255.255.255.255 [gateway ip]
```